# MySQLI Update Statement not working

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  include '../../connection.php';
    $id_e = $_POST['id'];
    $location_e = $_POST['location'];
    $state_e = $_POST['state'];
    $notes_e = $_POST['notes'];

  $sql="UPDATE chassis SET location='%$location_e%', state='%$state_e%', notes='%$notes_e%' WHERE id='%$id_e%'";

  $query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

  if (!$query) {
      echo json_encode(["message"=>mysqli_error($db)]);
  }else {
    echo json_encode(["message"=>"Success"]);
  }

/* I used this code below to check if the data sent by ajax is received
        switch($state_e){
            case "New":
            echo json_encode(["message"=>"hi"]);
            break;
        default:
            echo json_encode(["message"=>"nope"]);
            break;
        }
      }*/
 ?>
```

Hi, I'm not sure what the problem with my code is but the UPDATE statement isn't updating my database. I have an ajax jquery posting data which is received by this PHP file. I know that the data is being received by the PHP file because I tried a the piece of code to check it. Also, the query is returning success. I think the problem lies with the UPDATE statement however, I've tried different variations of the UPDATE statement like:

```
 $sql="UPDATE chassis SET location='".$_POST['location']."', state='".$_POST['state']."', notes='".$_POST['notes']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."";
```

It still doesn't work. I also checked the privileges on the SQL and I have All privileges.  Please help, I'm a high school student and this is for my end of year project. Cheers :)

Comment: get the right error from the failed query `mysqli_error($db);` Also why are you adding `%` next to the variables? .

Comment: @Akintunde007 How do I get the error? In the if statement above, it goes to Success.

Comment: echo out the sql after you've injected your variables in it, paste that query into your database and see what happens. Then fix it based on any errors you see in, then read up on SQL injection.

Comment: `WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."";`  Your quotes are mismatched there.

Comment: Why are you adding % into insert variables? have you tried escaping them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using prepared statements. Also i do not see the reason for adding the `%` next to the variables as per my comment. Also you should be getting the real error and not just outputting `Error`

```
$sql="UPDATE chassis SET location=?, state=?, notes=? WHERE id=?";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->bind_param('sssi', $location_e, $state_e, $notes_e, $id_e);
echo $result->execute() === true ? 'Success' : 'Failed: '.$result->error;
```

Comment: my pleasure.. :)